# Не отправляется email после оплаты товара WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте стоит Яндекс.Касса. Если заказ не был оплачен, администратору приходит уведомление о новом товаре. В случае, когда заказ оплатили онлайн, сообщение админу не приходит. Как можно это сделать?
Скорее всего стандартным методом это не делается, возможно знаете файл или событие, которые можно подредактировать

Comment: админу приходит уведомление о новом ТОВАРЕ?

Comment: Возможно используется старый плагин я.кассы. Сигнал на отправку письма должен отправить плагин, а если он этого не делает - стоит обратиться к его разработчику

Comment: админу не приходит при оплате через Яндекс.Кассу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно отправлять письмо в момент, когда заказ переходит в статус **Обработка**.

Можно попробовать что-то типа такого:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-order-processing', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 10 );
```